# RailsAdmin DSL - Show all fields, with only one read_only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In order to make a model attribute read only in the rails_admin panel you must do something like this:

```
  config.model Style do
    field :review_count do
      read_only true
    end
  end
```

The problem with doing this is now Style shows no other fields. I don't want to manually go through each model adding in the fields with this DSL. Is there a way to include all fields as editable by default while making one or two read only?

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **configure** instead of **field**

```
config.model Style do
  configure :review_count do
    read_only true
  end
end
```